# Custom Disk Spanning in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way `Components` section based custom disk spanning?

For example:

```
[Components]
Name: "c1"; Description: "Component 1"
Name: "sc2"; Description: "Special Component 2"
Name: "redist"; Description: "Redistributables"

[Files]
Source: component.exe; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: c1
Source: "specialfolder\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: sc2
Source: redist.msi; DestDir: "{app}"; Components: redist
```

The files that i want to see after compile: `setup.exe, c1.bin, special.bin, redist.bin`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

If your intention was to allow user to get only the pieces he/she needs, you can use the `extern` flag and `{src}` source directory instead. Though this is not really disk spanning. But it would allow the user to have just the files needed for the installation along the `setup.exe`. If you really need to store the files on separate disks, you can implement a prompt for additional disks and an actual installation in Pascal script.

Comment: Are you sure? I mean no disrespect, but I have seen a Inno based setup program like my example. Maybe it needs an external DLL library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure. What some programs? Show us some example.

Comment: I found a couple of links but they are torrent site llnks. I'm not sure that sharing a torrent site link is allowed. The examples belong the game repacks of a person who nickname is FitGirl.

Examples:
[link](https://kat.cr/deadlight-director-s-cut-multi5-fitgirl-repack-selective-download-from-2-1-gb-t12814808.html)

[link](https://kat.cr/lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens-2-dlc-multi10-fitgirl-repack-selective-download-from-6-3-gb-t12874097.html)

Comment: That installer implements the "disk spanning" in a Pascal script. The `.bin` files are compressed with Arc and the installer has `unarc.dll` embedded to extract them. The files are not listed in the `[Files]` section at all.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I notice it now. Thank you for your interest.